# Defining a variable in a C++ function that's already an argument name

Tags: c++, variables, arguments

What happens, in C++, if you define a variable in a function body with the same name as one of the function's arguments?

For example:

```
static void f(int i)
{
    int i;

    ...

}
```

Does the definition of `i` inside the function do anything?

Does it cause any harm?

Is there any good reason you can think of to write a function this way?

Comment: It shouldn't compile. The local `i` shadows the parameter.

Comment: *Does [it] do anything?* It makes the code not compile.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering because I thought I saw this in existing code. It turns out that the argument was `varname`, while the local variable  was `var_name`. Annoying, but not technically broken.

Comment: You could have tried this out yourself, you know.

Comment: @IsaacMoses If you thought you saw it, maybe there were extra braces in between.  The answer for `{ { int i; } }` is different from the answer for `{ int i; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ STandard

> **A parameter name shall not be redeclared in the outermost block** of the
>   function definition nor in the outermost block of any handler
>   associated with a function-try-block.

The compiler shall isuue a diagnostoc message in such a case.